# Offset SwiperJS pagination by one slide

Tags: swiper.js

This should be fairly simple, probably too simple, given I cannot find the API reference as of how to control it.

I am using https://swiperjs.com/ to build a simple slider of images.
Specifically, this one https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/5nclhv?file=%2Findex.html

Now, I want the slider to start at Slide Item 2, not item 1.
Yet, I cannot find any single option or API control to offset the initial pagination by one.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-initialSlide:
`initialSlide`

This parameter has default value `0` and defines the index number of initial slide.

Thus, setting it to `1` will make the slider start at the second slide item.